# Existence of homotopically non-trivial inclusion map from $X\simeq \mathbb{S}^6$ to $Y\simeq \mathbb{S}^4\vee \mathbb{S}^7$

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $X$ be a subcomplex of a simplicial complex $Y$ such that $X\simeq \mathbb{S}^6$ and $Y\simeq \mathbb{S}^7\vee\mathbb{S}^4$.

> **Question:** Is the inclusion map $i :X \longrightarrow Y$ always null homotopic?

Any ideas or references are greatly appreciated!

Comment: No. $\pi_6(S^7\vee S^4)\cong \pi_6(S^4)\cong \mathbb Z/2$. There is a non-trivial map $S^6\to S^7\vee S^4$. Using the mapping cylinder construction and simplicial approximation you can realize this map as an inclusion of a simplicial subcomplex.

Comment: Maybe you should post this as an answer (I don't think there's anything to be added at all)

Comment: Thank you @GregoryArone!